# Need to retrieve latitude and longitude of the center of the triggered geofence, but Hash-Map is returning null

Tags: java, android, hashmap, geofencing, android-geofence

I want to retrieve the latitude and longitude of the geofence created, In the GeoFenceBroadcastReceiver.java class for which i thought of using a hashMap (where i would use the ID of the geofence as the key and in-return would get the LatLng of the center of the geofence as value) but alas hashMap is Empty and returning null value when checked in the logcat. geoFenceHelper.setHashmap (method created in GeoFenceHelper.java) is used within addGeoFence() in MapsActivity.java {setHashMap is at the bottom of the GeoFenceHelper.java class} and then using getGeoFenceLatLng(String ID) in GeoFenceBroadcastReceiver.java to retrieve the LatLng.

Again to sum-up, I thought using a hashMap to create a key-value pair between the geofence Id and geofence LatLng would help me, but the hashMap is returning null, I don't want null, but the value (LatLng). Do solve this problem and help if it possible.

In MapsActivity.java

```
@Override
public void onMapLongClick(LatLng latLng) {
    float GEO_FENCE_RADIUS = 300;
    addGeoFence(latLng, GEO_FENCE_RADIUS);
}

private void addGeoFence(LatLng latLng, float geo_fence_radius) {
    String ID = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
    Log.d(TAG, "addGeoFence: String ID generated: " + ID);
    Log.d(TAG, "addGeoFence: LatLng latLng generated: " + latLng);

    Geofence geofence = geoFenceHelper.getGeoFence(ID, latLng, geo_fence_radius, Geofence.GEOFENCE_TRANSITION_ENTER |
            Geofence.GEOFENCE_TRANSITION_DWELL | Geofence.GEOFENCE_TRANSITION_EXIT);

    GeofencingRequest geofencingRequest = geoFenceHelper.getGeoFencingRequest(geofence);

    PendingIntent pendingIntent = geoFenceHelper.getPendingIntent();

    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) { return; }
    geofencingClient.addGeofences(geofencingRequest, pendingIntent)
            .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Void>() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(Void aVoid) { Log.d(TAG, "onSuccess: GeoFence has been added"); }
            })
            .addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                @Override
                public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception exception) {
                    String error = geoFenceHelper.getErrorString(exception);
                    Log.d(TAG, "onFailure: GeoFence not added " + error); }
            });

    Log.d(TAG, "addGeoFence: String ID set To GeoFence: " + ID);
    Log.d(TAG, "addGeoFence: LatLng latLng set To GeoFence: " + latLng);

    geoFenceHelper.setHashMap(ID,latLng);    //This will call the setHashMap
}
```

In GeoFenceHelper.java

```
public class GeoFenceHelper extends ContextWrapper {

private static final String TAG = "GeoFenceHelper";

PendingIntent pendingIntent;
HashMap<String, LatLng> hashMap = new HashMap<>();

private static final int PENDING_INTENT_REQUEST_CODE = 234;

public GeoFenceHelper(Context base) { super(base); }

public Geofence getGeoFence(String ID, LatLng latLng, float radius, int TransitionTypes){
    return new Geofence.Builder()
            .setCircularRegion(latLng.latitude,latLng.longitude,radius)
            .setExpirationDuration(Geofence.NEVER_EXPIRE)
            .setLoiteringDelay(2000)
            .setRequestId(ID)
            .setTransitionTypes(TransitionTypes)
            .build();
}

public GeofencingRequest getGeoFencingRequest(Geofence geofence){
    return new GeofencingRequest.Builder()
            .addGeofence(geofence)
            .setInitialTrigger(GeofencingRequest.INITIAL_TRIGGER_ENTER)
            .build();
}

public PendingIntent getPendingIntent(){
    if (pendingIntent != null){ return pendingIntent; }
    Intent intent = new Intent(GeoFenceHelper.this,GeoFenceBroadcastReceiver.class);
    pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(GeoFenceHelper.this,PENDING_INTENT_REQUEST_CODE,intent,PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    return pendingIntent;
}

public String getErrorString(Exception e) {
    if (e instanceof ApiException) {
        ApiException apiException = (ApiException) e;
        switch (apiException.getStatusCode()) {
            case GeofenceStatusCodes.GEOFENCE_NOT_AVAILABLE:
                return "GEO_FENCE NOT AVAILABLE";
            case GeofenceStatusCodes.GEOFENCE_TOO_MANY_GEOFENCES:
                return "GEO_FENCE TOO MANY GEO_FENCES";
            case GeofenceStatusCodes.GEOFENCE_TOO_MANY_PENDING_INTENTS:
                return "GEO_FENCE TOO MANY PENDING INTENTS";
        }
    }
    return e.getLocalizedMessage();
}

public LatLng getGeoFenceLatLng(String ID) {
    Log.d(TAG, "getGeoFenceLatLng: the Id passed is: " + ID);

    if (this.hashMap.isEmpty()){
        Log.d(TAG, "getGeoFenceLatLng: HashMap is Empty");
        Toast.makeText(this, "HashMap is Empty", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    LatLng latLng = hashMap.get(ID);
    Log.d(TAG, "getHashMap: the LatLng in the hashMap is: " + latLng);
    return latLng;
}

public void setHashMap(String ID, LatLng latLng) {
    this.hashMap.put(ID,latLng);
    Log.d(TAG, "setHashMap: ID of the geoFence: " + ID);
    Log.d(TAG, "setHashMap: latLng of the geoFence: " + latLng);
}
```

}

In GeoFenceBroadcastReceiver.java

```
public class GeoFenceBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

private static final String TAG = "GeoFenceBroadcastRec";
Location location;
LatLng latLng;

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    Log.d(TAG, "onReceive: geoFence added");

    GeofencingEvent geofencingEvent = GeofencingEvent.fromIntent(intent);

    GeoFenceHelper geoFenceHelper = new GeoFenceHelper(context);
    NotificationHelper notificationHelper = new NotificationHelper(context);

    if (geofencingEvent.hasError()) {
        Log.d(TAG, "onReceive: Error receiving geoFence event..." + geofencingEvent.getErrorCode());
        return;
    }

    List<Geofence> geoFenceList = geofencingEvent.getTriggeringGeofences();
    for (Geofence geofence: geoFenceList) {
        String ID = geofence.getRequestId();
        Log.d(TAG, "onReceive: RequestId of the geoFence: " + ID);
        latLng = geoFenceHelper.getGeoFenceLatLng(ID);
        Log.d(TAG, "onReceive: LatLng in hashMap: " + latLng);
    }

    location = geofencingEvent.getTriggeringLocation();
    Log.d(TAG, "onReceive: user location where it got detected: " + location.getLatitude() + " " + location.getLongitude());

    int transitionType = geofencingEvent.getGeofenceTransition();

    switch (transitionType) {
        case Geofence.GEOFENCE_TRANSITION_ENTER:
            Log.d(TAG, "onReceive: " + "GEO_FENCE TRANSITION ENTER");
            Toast.makeText(context, "GEO_FENCE TRANSITION ENTER", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            break;
        case Geofence.GEOFENCE_TRANSITION_DWELL:
            Log.d(TAG, "onReceive: " + "GEO_FENCE TRANSITION DWELL");
            Toast.makeText(context, "GEO_FENCE TRANSITION DWELL", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            break;
        case Geofence.GEOFENCE_TRANSITION_EXIT:
            Log.d(TAG, "onReceive: " + "GEO_FENCE TRANSITION EXIT");
            Toast.makeText(context, "GEO_FENCE TRANSITION EXIT", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            break;
    }
}
```

}

If there is another way to get the latitude and longitude of the geofence triggered do tell me, if not then please try to solve this.

Comment: Check if register receiver via registerReceiver or <receiver> tag in XML, and check if the broadcast sent successfully

Comment: Well, broadcast reciever is working fine as it is giving toast messages of enter and exit, reciever is also in android manifest file... My main problem is with hashmap being empty, i want my hashmap to have LatLng available...